# The best way to compare row details in table

Tags: tables

What is the best solution to represent more details in tables?
[image: Version A] [image: Version B][image: Vesrion C]

**What is this page about.**
This page contains logs (history of changes) for some rules. Imagine that admin set up a rule and then another admin modified the rule. There could be many modifications made by different admins. All the modifications will be reflected in the table. We show "when" the rule was modified, "who" modified and details ("what exactly" was modified). What is the best way to show those details if we don't have enough space in the table?

Note: User wants to compare details from one row to another.

Answer (score 1):

If user wants to compare details from one row to another, option A would allow them to switch select different rows and visually compare results in the same space (the sidebar). Not so with the drawer. And the modal would be cumbersome to click, close, choose another row, close, etc.

Comment: Why "Version B" is not an option? User can open (expand) 2 rows and compare them just using scroll and not clicking anywhere.

Comment: Version B doesn't work if they want to compare the top and bottom row of the table since it would be out of view.

Comment: well, not necessarily. Both will be visible completely or with a minimum scroll. Check this out http://prntscr.com/g63c5j

Comment: Sorry if my first comment was unclear. Since the OP's image shows that the table extends beyond the view of the screen (ie, the you have to scroll to see the last row), that means that you cannot view the top row and the bottom row of the table at the same time (much less compare their details).